# Make `select` dropdown appear without a fixed width

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

For various reasons, I'm trying to "un-style" a `select` option list in order to appear inline with the surrounding text.

I was able to get very close, but there seems to be some sort of forced width for the dropdown. I'm trying to get the width of the `select` to grow or shrink to match the selected value.

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  
  /* doesn't work in Safari */
  min-width: auto;
  max-width: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>
  I want an inline
  <select>
  <option>First option</option>
  <option>Second option has a longer title</option>
  <option>Yet another option here</option>
  </select>
  that doesn't have a forced width.
 </p>
```

I tried setting `min-` and `max-width` to `auto`, with no luck.

If there isn't a pure CSS solution, is there a lightweight way to calculate the desired width in JavaScript? FWIW, I'm using Vue.js and not really concerned with the line-wrapping as much as the fixed width.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35567067/how-to-make-the-selected-option-the-width-of-the-current-selected-options-text refer this if may help

Comment: this is a good solution https://jsfiddle.net/Hatchet/a0xzz6mf/

Comment: Thanks, folks. Appreciate the comments and solutions. Didn't uncover them during my searches.

Comment: Check out the answer I just put in the other question. I think it'll probably end up a bit more reliable cross-browser/platform then the answers currently there.